# How to show tooltip over colored/stacked region of stacked line chart in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a chartjs stacked bar chart. I am showing tooltip on hover of plotted points. Moreover, I want to show tooltip on hover of colored/stacked region

Below is my chart

[image]

On hover of blue area, I want to show "Region A" in tooltip and on hover of green area I want to show "Region B" in tooltip.

My tooltip configuration is as below:

```
{
  tooltips: {
    displayColors: false,
    callbacks: {
      title: () => {
        return null
      },
      label: function(tooltipItem) {
        const event = R.pathOr(
          {},
          ['_data', 'datasets', tooltipItem.datasetIndex, 'data', tooltipItem.index],
          this
        )
        return [event.title, event.value, event.status]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code on how you are adding the tooltip currently?

Comment: @gnahum updated the description

Comment: Have you seen this doc? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

I think the function can be `function (tooltipItem, data)` where data can be which region you use.

Comment: You're right - function can be `function (tooltipItem, data)`. 
Thanks for your answer.
How do I get tooltip on hover of blue/green region?

Comment: I'm assuming that the blue/green region are two different datasets. I think you can change via which dataset it is. i.e. In the interactions.html sample it was mode was nearest and intersect to be true for the config. As shown here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/tooltips/interactions.html#L36-L67

Comment: I'm assuming that the blue/green region are two different datasets. I think you can change via which dataset it is. i.e. In the interactions.html sample it was mode was nearest and intersect to be true for the config. As shown here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/tooltips/interactions.html#L36-L67

Comment: `intersect: true, mode: 'nearest'` didn't work. However, with `intersect: false, mode: 'nearest'` I am able to get tooltip on hover of blue/green region. By doing this change, on hovering over colored region, it is highlighting and showing tooltip of nearest plot. Ideally, I want to show `label` in tooltip in such scenario. This is a progress, but I'm still not there

Comment: Shouldn't the label function return a string? i.e. `var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';`

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: @gnahum Thanks for your answer. I am required to show multiple information on the tooltip of plots(see my attached screenshot above). For that purpose, I need to return an array here.
You're right. For the tooltip of the colored region it should return just the label as a string. Sad part is that with `intersect: true` when I hover over colored region, label callback is not called. and with `intersect: false`, label callback is called in context of nearest plot

Comment: To show multiple information, can't you concatenate a string? Also if you do `intersect: true`, the call back doesn't run even if you say `function(toolTipItem, data)`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't run, even with `function(toolTipItem, data)`

Answer (score 0):

(assuming chartjs 4.3) Adding `intersect:false` seems to give the result.

Note that the hover popup is showing (top to bottom) Blue then Green - but the stacking is (top to bottom) Green then Blue... another thought is that if you can't restrict the popup to show just the value then at least show the list in the same order as the chart.

Also adding plugins/tooltip/callbacks can customize the text in the hover - but I can't work out how to show JUST the area you are hovering over....

```
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    callbacks: {
      label: function(context) {
        var datasetLabel = context.dataset.label || '';
        var value = context.raw.y;

        return context.datasetIndex + ' vs ' + context.dataIndex + ' ... ' + context.dataset.label + ' : ' + context.label + ' = ' + context.formattedValue;
      } // label
    } // end callbacks:
  } //end tooltip
} // end plugins
```

This will show a hover for all series (with a value on the date) in the chart..

[image]

See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/8df305xg/20/ for a running example